# Nginx + passenger +rails : Getting 405 error on post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'm having a 405 error when I call a post request to a rails controller action.
The post request is used to get a json file wile the get request delivers a standard html page.
The problem is that the html is cached.

I've seen a solution for this problem on http://millarian.com/programming/ruby-on-rails/nginx-405-not-allowed-error/

```
if ($request_method != GET) {
  proxy_pass http://foobar;
  break;
}
```

the url in proxy_pass is the normally the url for the mongrel server. Is there similar solution for passenger ?

I'm a complete nginx newbie, trying to migrate from apache.

Comment: Are you actually posting data with the POST request or are you just using it to differentiate a JSON from HTML request? If so there is a better way to accomplish what you are doing.

Comment: I'd like rails to serve the json resquet instead of nginx returning a 405 error.

Comment: and yes I'm sending a post request. When I turn off the page caching, it works well.

Comment: Have you tried adding that line to your Nginx config file? You shouldn't have to change anything to get it work in Passenger if it already works in Mongrel.

Comment: No I didn't because I don't know what url to use for passenger. Mongrel uses a specific port.

Comment: Mongrel and Passenger standalone use the 3000 port, but when in combination with Nginx neither uses a port. Nginx is connected to port 80/81 or 3000 for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a way around. 
I had a set of rewrite conditions to deal with the cache directory my configuration of Rails uses.

```
# Check the path + .html
if (-f $document_root/cache/$uri.html) {
  rewrite (.*) /cache/$1.html break;
}
```

...

Those rewrites were applied even if the request was a POST, leading to the 405 error.

I managed to apply the rewrite only if the request is a GET. I'm not sure if it is the most efficient solution, but it seems to work. Learning how to deal with multiple conditions in Nginx was the trickiest part. (source : http://wiki.nginx.org/RewriteMultiCondExample)

```
set $dest "";

if ($request_method = GET) {
    set $dest "/cache";
}
# Check / files with index.html
if (-f $document_root/cache/$uri/index.html) {
  set $dest $dest/$uri/index.html ;
}

# Check the path + .html
if (-f $document_root/cache/$uri.html) {
  set $dest $dest/$uri.html ;
}

# Check directly
if (-f $document_root/cache/$uri) {
  set $dest $dest/$uri ;
}

if ($dest ~* ^/cache/(.*)$) {
    rewrite (.*) $dest break;
}
```

Any better solution?